# Login redirect with asp.Core 2.0 and React

Tags: authentication, redirect, react-router, asp.net-core-2.0

I've got a component from sample project that comes along when creating new React application with VS - `FetchData`. It's routed like `<Route path='/fetchdata/:startDateIndex?' component={ FetchData } />` and basically what it does is a call to the `SampleDataController` retrieving generated information about weather `IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts(int startDateIndex)`.

By default it's all great, but I want to see how React works with authentication. So I've fixed that controller with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Now the `Startup.cs` contains configuration to enable authentication - the same way you'd do that without React.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
            });
app.UseAuthentication();
```

So typically you get redirected to that login page for authentication and then you can navigate back (or use returnUrl for automatic redirection after success). But when the method on controller that requires authorization is invoked, the following things happen:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 77.3867ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:56021/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FSampleData%2FWeatherForecasts%3FstartDateIndex%3D0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method Project.Controllers.HomeController.Index with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

I've tried configuring additional routes for login, like so:
    `<Route path='/account/login:returnUrl?' component={Login} /><Route path='/account/login' component={Login} />` but it didn't change anything.

I can see that the redirect request is received by the browser. But the redirection does not occur. Can it be because of the request for `WeatherForecasts` is done just to fetch some data and not actually redirect?

The request code:

```
let fetchTask = fetch(`api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts?startDateIndex=${ startDateIndex }`)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
           dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_WEATHER_FORECASTS', startDateIndex: startDateIndex, forecasts: data });
     });
```

Also an important question: Is there a common way to handle that scenario?