# React SPA app with .net core backend and .net identity

Tags: api, react-redux, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I basically have the same question as what is detailed here: [Login redirect with asp.Core 2.0 and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337368).  But that post never got an answer.

I've searched quite a bit and pretty much my problem is also touched on here here:  https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1440

I want to create a react front end application, but use .net core for the backend.  I've used the .net core template with react redux as my boilerplate.  I've also configured the .net identity on my backend.  So I can actually use [Authorize] on my api calls and it works.  By this I mean that if someone is authenticated the api returns data and if no one is authenticated it returns whatever the default redirect page is.  I can confirm this by looking at the response on my chrome debugger and I see that it is showing the html for the register page which I've defaulted my login path to in configureapplicationcookie options.

The boiler plate is setup to serve up pages from the react client folder and uses react router.  Therefore, I cannot set up any links to pages on my server.  However, I'm able to manually navigate to my server pages for example /Account/Login and successfully login.  My api calls through the links on the react front end then seem to work just as I would like.

What I would like to do is:

1. make calls from my react application to my server api
2. upon unsuccessful access to any api endpoint, redirect the user/request to my register page on the .net core server
3. have the user register and/or login and then redirect them to the route they came from through the react application.

Is this possible? Is it advisable?

I understand that you can manage all this on the front end using IdentityServer as detailed here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html.  However, if all the infrastructure can be quickly spun up in .net and I can leverage the authentication templates, then I want to experiment with that setup and save time.  Plus if this is feasible, why bother doing the setup on the front end using a 3rd party login provider?  What am I missing?