# React SPA with .net core API, authentication

Tags: c#, reactjs, authentication

I would like to write a SPA application in React that will communicate with the .net core API.
I think it would be easier to have two separate projects (API + UI) on different domains.

API should be protected, that only authenticated users could make requests.
In react i'd like to have login and registration forms that will allow me to register and login users, and also I would like to have social providers. I would like to create whole UI for managing users in react SPA, and saving this data using API.

I did a lot of research, and I'm a little confused.
I would really like to use Core Identity because it simply looks like made for it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0

- it has a ready to go model of Users, Claims, Roles etc.
- it has built in services for managing passwords, users, roles etc
- it has features to customize authentication schemes, policies, roles etc,

there are lot of reasons why i think this is a good solution.

Unfortunatelly, on the documentation site there is an information that for SPA integration it works combined with Identity Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Last year I went throug every episode of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fhfvbl_KbWo&ab_channel=RawCodingRawCoding (btw. great tutorial), and I'm pretty sure, that I don't want to use Identity Server 4 for this scenario. As far as I know - this is the best solution when you want to have SSO for multiple applications, and you would like to provide one common way to authenticate user for all of it. And it has it's own UI for managing user registration, login and managing. This is not what I need - I just want to have it all written in React, cause I want all application to have the same mui theme without redirects to Identity Server.

But maybe I'm wrong, and Identity Server will work for me. But I found it to be quite lot of work to provide my own UI rather than MVC
(https://medium.com/@piotrkarpaa/using-spa-react-angular-ui-with-identity-server-4-dc1f57e90b2c)

For now I think, that I should use Identity Core on the backend, and communicate with it from React SPA with custom controllers like in here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/

Authenticating React SPA with API with JWT token - I think that this will work according to this example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSUa8Vd-td0&ab_channel=Geek%27sLesson - but in here this is without Identity Core.

But I'm not sure that this is the best approach, and I don't know if I will be able to add Social Providers this way.

Also, I found serveral tutorials how to comine React App with .net core backend (and authentication) like this one:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/integrate-create-react-app-with-net-core-5/

but I would like to have two separate applications, API and UI.

What is the best approach to achieve this goal?

**EDIT:**

Few months later, I already have SPA application, API and IS4. There is lot of problems to make Identity Server views (registration, login etc) look similar to SPA Application. (React app in MUI, MVC with bootstrap... ).

Now I think it was a bad decision, causing lot of problems:

2 way integration of users from API and Identity Server 4
changes in SPA layout, styles, colors - it all needs to be maintened on Identity Server 4 too
Bad user expirience - editing user profile on another application, on another domain with slightly different styles
Now I'm about to rewrite application, not to use Identity Server 4. Components for registration, login and editing user profile will be in SPA application, maintaining users will be done using API.

The only think I do not know is how can I use social providers with this aproach?

My question is still remaining without answer, can someone help me with providing proper solution?

Comment: There are many ways to do this and several guides around the web. Have you done any research? Using JWT for authentication is a pretty common approach. And BTW, Identity does not force you to use Razor pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I eddited my question and added more Information about what I already researched.

Comment: So if you want to manage your users yourself (and not use login through Google, Facebook etc.) then Identity should work just fine for you. Generating a JWT should be the same regardless of how you manage the users.

Comment: The problem is, that I would really like to have a possibility to login and register with social providers.. without password. Is that possible with .net core identity and react?

Comment: I'm unsure whether it's considered part of Identity, but yes you can definitely use login with social providers alongside Identity - [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). React is something completely separate - it's just a front end layer and really doesn't have much to do with all the other stuff. So yes, you can of course use React too :)

Comment: In this docs, this social authentication schemas use coockies, which i will not be able to use, because of different domains. I think that my only supported way would be:
1) sign in user on the front side and obtain identity token JWT
2) call anonymous access enabled endpoint for validating this JWT id token
a) if valid and there is user in my identity DB, then return access token with all claims
b) if valid and there is and there is not user in DB then return data for prefilled registration form and external provider id
c) if token invalid return 401
All of this seems quite complicated

Comment: another option is to use identity as a service, for example azure b2c. But in this scenario i found that user flows are not enough for me and I will need to use Custom Policies (for example to add verification code for invitations). For me this is very complex, and I wonder if there Is any easier way to achive my simple goal described in the question

Comment: Another people have similar problems, like in here, but remaining without solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989736/react-spa-app-with-net-core-backend-and-net-identity

Comment: I think you need to gather a bit more practical knowledge for yourself. This thread is spinning in circles a bit and we're talking about theoretical things. You should try it out and see how it works - don't overload yourself with problems before digging in and getting and understanding of how things can be set up. Do some quick testing. I don't think there's a problem using login from social providers together with JWT. I haven't done this personally, but I don't see why it should be a problem. Research is not just about reading, it's also about getting your hands dirty.

Comment: I'm just asking what is the best approach. I've already written working examples of every topic I mentioned. I have POC of working authentication with scenario I described, but didn't found anything similar, and i'm asking if this is OK

Comment: Why not mention that in the question? If you have something that's working then go with that. With so many parameters/requirements there's no such thing as a commonly agreed upon "best approach". A good advice in programming: don't optimize prematurely/ before you really need to. If it works they way it's supposed to, then stick with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232881/discussion-between-mateuszwdowiak-and-xerillio).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found proper solution for me:

https://mahdikarimipour.com/blog/google-auth-for-react-with-aspnet-identity

thank you for your post: Mahdi Karimipour

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).